# Trie Implementation Question

Tags: trie

I'm implementing a trie for predictive text entry in VB.NET - basically autocompletion as far as the use of the trie is concerned.  I've made my trie a recursive data structure based on the generic dictionary class.

It's basically:

```
class WordTree Inherits Dictionary(of Char, WordTree)
```

Each letter in a word (all upper cased) is used as a key to a new WordTrie.  A null character on a leaf indicates the termination of a word.  To find a word starting with a prefix I walk the trie as far as my prefix goes then collect all children words.

My question is basically on the implementation of the trie itself.  I'm using the dictionary hash function to branch my tree.  I could use a list and do a linear search over the list, or do something else.  What's the smooth move here?  Is this a reasonable way to do my branching?

Thanks.

Update:

Just to clarify, I'm basically asking if the dictionary branching approach is obviously inferior to some other alternative.  The application in which I'm using this data structure only uses upper case letters, so maybe the array approach is the best.  I might use the same data structure for a more complex typeahead situation in the future (more characters).  In that case, it sounds like the dictionary is the right approach - up to the point where I need to use something more complex in general.

Comment: is this just a-z? i.e. no internationalization

Comment: Yes, just 26 letters plus the null character.

Comment: can you provide more feedback, so that we can answer the question completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just the 26 letters, as a 26 entry array. Then lookup is by index.  It probably uses less space than the Dictionary if the bucket-list is longer than 26.

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried about space, you can use bitmap compression on the valid byte transitions, assuming the 26char limit.

```
class State  // could be struct or whatever
{
    int valid; // can handle 32 transitions -- each bit set is valid
    vector<State> transitions;

    State getNextState( int ch )
    {
         int index;
         int mask  = ( 1 << ( toupper( ch ) - 'A' )) -1;
         int bitsToCount = valid & mask;

         for( index = 0; bitsToCount ; bitsToCount  >>= 1)
         {
             index  += bitsToCount  & 1;
         }  
         transitions.at( index );
    }
};
```

There are other ways to do the bit counting [Here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive), the index into the vector is the number of set bits in the valid bitset. the other alternative is the direct indexed array of states;

```
class State
{
    State transitions[ 26 ]; // use the char as the index.

    State getNextState( int ch )
    {
        return transitions[ ch ];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

A good data structure that's efficient in space and potentially gives sub-linear prefix lookups is the ternary search tree. [Peter Kankowski has a *fantastic* article](http://www.strchr.com/ternary_dags) about it. He uses C, but it's straightforward code once you understand the data structure. As he mentioned, this is the structure ispell uses for spelling correction.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this (a trie implementation) in C with 8 bit chars, and simply used the array version (as alluded to by the "26 chars" answer).

HOWEVER, I am guessing that you want full unicode support (since a .NET char is unicode, among other reasons).  Assuming you have to have support for unicode, the hash/map/dictionary lookup is probably your best bet, as a 64K entry array in each node won't really work very well.

About the only hack up I could think of on this is to store entire strings (suffixes or possibly "in-fixes") on branches that do not yet split, depending on how sparse the tree, er, trie, is.  That adds a lot of logic to detect the multi-char strings, though, and to split them up when an alternate path is introduced.

What is the read vs update pattern?

---- update jul 2013 ---

If .NET strings have a function like java to get the bytes for a string (as UTF-8), then having an array in each node to represent the current position's byte value is probably a good way to go.  You could even make the arrays variable size, with first/last bounds indicators in each node, since MANY nodes will have only lower case ASCII letters anyway, or only upper case letters or the digits 0-9 in some cases.

Comment: As it stands now, new words are not added to the trie.  It's built periodically on a batch basis.  I may add functionality to capture new words as they are entered in the future.  In that case it would be a more balanced read/update situation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [burst trie's](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~jz/fulltext/acmtois02.pdf) to be very space efficient. I wrote my own [burst trie in Scala](https://github.com/nbauernfeind/scala-burst-trie) that also re-uses some ideas that I found in GWT's trie implementation. I used it in Stripe's Capture the Flag contest on a problem that was multi-node with a small amount of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

```
// we start with the TrieNode
const TrieNode = function (key) {
  // the "key" value will be the character in sequence
  this.key = key;
  
  // we keep a reference to parent
  this.parent = null;
  
  // we have hash of children
  this.children = {};
  
  // check to see if the node is at the end
  this.end = false;
  
  this.getWord = function() {
    let output = [];
    let node = this;

    while (node !== null) {
      output.unshift(node.key);
      node = node.parent;
    }

    return output.join('');
  };
}

const Trie = function() {
  this.root = new TrieNode(null);
  
  // inserts a word into the trie.
  this.insert = function(word) {
    let node = this.root; // we start at the root

    // for every character in the word
    for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      // check to see if character node exists in children.
      if (!node.children[word[i]]) {
        // if it doesn't exist, we then create it.
        node.children[word[i]] = new TrieNode(word[i]);

        // we also assign the parent to the child node.
        node.children[word[i]].parent = node;
      }

      // proceed to the next depth in the trie.
      node = node.children[word[i]];

      // finally, we check to see if it's the last word.
      if (i == word.length-1) {
        // if it is, we set the end flag to true.
        node.end = true;
      }
    }
  };
  
  // check if it contains a whole word.
  this.search = function(word) {
    let node = this.root;

    // for every character in the word
    for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      // check to see if character node exists in children.
      if (node.children[word[i]]) {
        // if it exists, proceed to the next depth of the trie.
        node = node.children[word[i]];
      } else {
        // doesn't exist, return false since it's not a valid word.
        return false;
      }
    }

    // we finished going through all the words, but is it a whole word?
    return node.end;
  };
  
  // returns every word with given prefix
  this.startsWith = function(prefix) {
    let node = this.root;
    let output = [];

    // for every character in the prefix
    for(let i = 0; i < prefix.length; i++) {
      // make sure prefix actually has words
      if (node.children[prefix[i]]) {
        node = node.children[prefix[i]];
      } else {
        // there's none. just return it.
        return output;
      }
    }

    // recursively find all words in the node
    findAllWords(node, output);

    return output;
  };
  
  // recursive function to find all words in the given node.
  const findAllWords = (node, arr) => {
    // base case, if node is at a word, push to output
    if (node.end) {
      arr.unshift(node.getWord());
    }

    // iterate through each children, call recursive findAllWords
    for (let child in node.children) {
      findAllWords(node.children[child], arr);
    }
  }

  // removes a word from the trie.
  this.remove = function (word) {
      let root = this.root;

      if(!word) return;

      // recursively finds and removes a word
      const removeWord = (node, word) => {

          // check if current node contains the word
          if (node.end && node.getWord() === word) {

              // check and see if node has children
              let hasChildren = Object.keys(node.children).length > 0;

              // if has children we only want to un-flag the end node that marks the end of a word.
              // this way we do not remove words that contain/include supplied word
              if (hasChildren) {
                  node.end = false;
              } else {
                  // remove word by getting parent and setting children to empty dictionary
                  node.parent.children = {};
              }

              return true;
          }

          // recursively remove word from all children
          for (let key in node.children) {
              removeWord(node.children[key], word)
          }

          return false
      };

      // call remove word on root node
      removeWord(root, word);
  };
}
```